# Function argument: abstract class or interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstraction

Suppose to have this class diagram, in Java:

```
<Interface>   <AbstractClass>      <ConcreteClass>      

                                   Γ SomethingImpl1
ISomething <- AbstractSomething <--|
                                   L SomethingImpl2
```

What I would like to know is what type should a function argument taking `Something` have.

Take `ICity` (and so on...) and `ILocation`. If `ILocation` has a function to set a City, e.g.:

```
void setCity(X city);
```

What should **X** be? `ICity` or `AbstractCity`? What is the correct signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ISomething`/`ICity` is the correct type for the parameter provided the method only needs the features provided by the interface (which should normally be the case). In general:

1. Code to the minimum interface you can, and
2. In Java, make that an `interface` where possible (as you have done); that way, if there were a good reason to implement it *not* via `AbstractSomething`/`AbstractCity`, you could, and still use it with the method.

Comment: What if, for example, my `City` needs to be Storable? Storable objects implement `IStorable` interface. But an interface cannot implement other interfaces and, even if it could, I won't be "favoring composition over inheritance" letting that possible. How could this be addressed? I could let `AbstractCity` implement `IStorable` but then functions taking `ICity` wouldn't know anything about that.

Comment: @mydriasis: If the method needs it to be both an `ICity` and an `IStorable`, then: `interface IStorableCity extends ICity, IStorable { }` and implement that. It would be great (in my view, on first glance) if Java allowed you to do `myMethod(ICity + IStorable city)` or something since it means if this wasn't anticipated ahead of time and you don't have access to `City`, you can't do that; but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! My only worry is that the number of classes/interfaces will soon explode with all this "composite entities", but I guess it's the price to pay...

Comment: @mydriasis: Yeah. I mean, the hack is to just accept an `ICity` and document in the JavaDoc that it also has to be `IStorable` and do an `instanceof` check (blech).